# Printing file content with grep

Tags: grep, stdout

Is it possible to print to the console all file content using only grep command? (wihtout cat, less, echo, more...)

Comment: There is, but I'm not sure why you'd want to, as even in the optimum cases @Ignacio describes it'd be slower than `cat`.

Comment: @Shadur Looks like exploiting a bug in/with `grep` must be the reason... Interesting.

Comment: no, I'm just playing a game which is a simulator for linux administration. I need to look what's in a file but I have only 11 commands - grep is among them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course. Every line has a beginning.

```
grep '^' file.txt
```

Comment: `''` (the empty pattern) also works since the empty string matches everywhere as well.